# How to write a generic method which initializes the type passed to that method?

Tags: c#

I have class which holds instances of other classes by means of properties with only GET.

```
public class PageInstance : PageInstanceBase
{
    #region Private Members

    private InquiryPage _inquiryPage;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Inquiry Page.
    /// </summary>
    public InquiryPage InquiryPage
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._inquiryPage == null)
            {
                this._inquiryPage = new InquiryPage();
            }

            return this._inquiryPage;
        }
    }
```

`}`

This class has more than 10 properties (10 different class instances). Now I want to write an explicit method where I can SET the values depending on the need and I do not want use SET in the existing properties.

Is it possible to do it with a generic method or by any means? Like...

```
public void Refresh<T>() where T : new()
    {
       _inquiryPage = new T();
    }
```

I got stuck at this place. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sham_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out the solution as mentioned below.But, this lead me to provide private/protected SET attribute for all properties. Constraint, Page has been inherited to PageInstanceBase and then to PageInstance.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh the Page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Page.</typeparam>
    public void Refresh<T>() where T : Page, new()
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(t.Name);
        pi.SetValue(this, new T(), null);
    }
```

Now while calling, I will call the page as Refresh< InquiryPage>(), which sets the this._inquiryPage to new Instance of InquiryPage class.

Thanks,

Sham_

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the some [`constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) as you did, but for some abstration like an `interface` or `abstract class`. For sample:

```
public void Refresh<T>() 
    where T : InquiryPage, new()
{
    _inquiryPage = new T();
}
```

In your case, I do not know what `InquiryPage` type is, but, if you have some abstration you could use on this method and keep the `new()` to say to CLR that this `T` generic type also have to had a empty constructor.

Or, make your classe generic, for sample:

```
public class PageInstance<T> : PageInstanceBase, 
    where T : new()           
{
    #region Private Members

    private T _inquiryPage;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public T InquiryPage
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._inquiryPage == null)
            {
                this._inquiryPage = new T();
            }

            return this._inquiryPage;
        }
    }

    public void Refresh() 
    {
       this._inquiryPage = new T();
    }
}
```

in generics, you just have in `T` type, what you have specified in constraints, in this case, an empty constructor.

Comment: I do have multiple classes, among them one is InquiryPage. All of the classes have a default constructor.

Comment: Do you some abstraction for all these classes? .Net Framework will not compile a `new T()` since it should be a `InquiryPage`. Add an interface for all classes; or You also could change your `_inquiryPage` to `T` and keep `T` on the class scope: `public class PageInstance<T> where T : new()`.

Comment: True, but this needs a lot of changes applicable. Any other suggestion  where there is no disturbance on existing signature?

Comment: In simple words, I need to initialize my page when I call refresh method. Like...
    PageInstance _page = new PageInstance();
    _page.InquiryPage.Refresh();
The above needs to write a method 'Refresh()' in InquiryPage, where I can initialize page and send the instance to object in PageInstance which is _inquiryPage???

Comment: Don't you can do a complete generic class? Look my edits